# Linux machine not recognizing android device

Tags: android, linux, mtp

I'm using a Linux Mint 18.1 Serena machine and have recently done some upgrades (including the Kernel to 4.4.0-62) and since my computer does not recongnize my Samsung j5 2016 phone.

I have tried to downgrade the kernel (and delete the newest version) but that did not help. After trying different solutions that didn't work I decided to format the machine but each time (after the booting process is done) when clicking on "Install linux now" nothing happens (I have tried with mint 18.1, 18.0 and 17.3).

- to make the USB bootable I've used the dd command (which worked just finesince I've formated my computer just a week ago)
- USB debugging is enabled on my device
- I am using MTP
- I am getting this message on my phone : The connected device is unable to access data on this device. Reconnect the USB cable and try again (and then saying that I should download some stuff if I'm using a Mac OS X)
- my device is running on Android 6.0.1
- running lsusb does not give any result
- running ./adb devices gives an empty list

I am open to any solution whether it's by formating or any other way.

Comment: Try running `adb` or `lsusb` as root. I recall something about permissions to the `usb` devices.. If it works, you will have to tweak your `udev` rules.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it didn't work

Comment: if you do not see the phone on lsusb output, you probably should try using another USB cable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took of the battery and it worked